# RUN pip install --upgrade pip and RUN pip install -r requirements.txt not working

Tags: docker, build, dockerfile

so here’s the story, this is my first time using docker because i was told it is really easy to deploy script, model and many more. Today i try to build my first docker image for my python script using flask. i try to build it and it work on the first couple of iteration and fail like 10 times on the RUN section this is the log

```
[+] Building 9.7s (9/10)                                                                                 docker:default
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                               0.9s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 682B                                                                               0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                  1.3s
 => => transferring context: 58B                                                                                   0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/python:3.9                                                      4.5s
 => [auth] library/python:pull token for registry-1.docker.io                                                      0.0s
 => [1/5] FROM 
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                  0.3s
 => => transferring context: 74B                                                                                   0.0s
 => CACHED [2/5] WORKDIR /flask-finding-driver                                                                     0.0s
 => CACHED [3/5] COPY finding_driver.py requirements.txt /flask-finding-driver/                                    0.0s
 => ERROR [4/5] RUN python -m pip install --upgrade pip                                                            2.1s
------
 > [4/5] RUN python -m pip install --upgrade pip:
1.565 exec /bin/sh: exec format error
------
Dockerfile:11
--------------------
   9 |
  10 |     # Install any needed packages specified in requirements.txt
  11 | >>> RUN python -m pip install --upgrade pip
  12 |     RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
  13 |
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c python -m pip install --upgrade pip" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1
```

this is my dockerfile :

```
FROM python:3.9

WORKDIR /flask-finding-driver

COPY finding_driver.py requirements.txt /flask-finding-driver/

RUN python -m pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

EXPOSE 5000

ENV FLASK_APP=finding_driver.py

CMD ["flask", "run", "--host=0.0.0.0"]
```

Well of course because of this i search on many places for advice especially in stack overflow  and implement it like dont upgrade pip, use python3, dont use pip to upgrade pip, dont run pip at all, etc i try everything and still fail. also when i delete this line

`RUN python -m pip install --upgrade pip`

it created another error same like this but for requirements.txt

so if anyone can help me solve this problem please do so because i already fixing this error for like 2-3 hours and thank you if youre answering this question really need it fast

Comment: If you're seeing `exec format error` on the very first `RUN` command, is it possible you're using an x86-based image on ARM hardware (like an M1/M2 Mac)?

Comment: omg is it this?  Architecture: x86_64, but im on windows tho is it matter?

Comment: You could run the base image and try to reproduce steps that you're doing in Dockerfile.
`docker run -it python3:9 bash`  This might give you better insight what might be the cause.